# Присвоить нескольким серверам один внешний IP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, администрирование

У нас есть 4  убунту сервера. 
Каждый имеет свой внешний ip.
Для работы с серверами нам нужен VNC.

Задача:
Нам нужно чтобы при любом выходе в интернет (браузер, запросы из приложений) внешний ip был у всех одинаковый. 
И при этом чтобы остался доступ к каждому серверу через VNC.

Подскажите как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: На маршрутизаторе NAT'ить исходящие соединения.

Comment: Нет доступа к маршрутизатору.  Сервера у хостера.

Comment: Тогда без вариантов.

Answer (score 1):

Сделать один из серверов шлюзом для остальных.
А доступ к vnc можно перенаправлением портов.

Минус - утилизация сети через один сервер. Но можно выбрать самый мощный сервер с хорошей сетевухой